# call a batch file from VBA in excel 2010

Tags: vba, batch-file

I am trying to call a `.bat` file from `VBA` using: however I am getting `Method Run of object IWshShell3 failed` with the line in asteriks highlighted.  I am not familiar with this error and don't know where to begin.  I am running VB in excel 2010.  Thank you :).

```
    Dim PathCrnt As String
    Dim wsh As Object

    PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & MyBarCode & "_" & MyScan
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    **wsh.Run "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat", windowStyle, waitOnReturn**
End If
```

**EDIT**

The code runs but exits with error code 1. Basically, what I am trying to do is have the user enter a barcode and date, those values are used to change the directory to that. A batch file is called that runs a `perl` script on that directory. The batch file is not being called and I'm not sure why. Thank you :).

*VBA*

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim MyBarCode   As String      ' Enter Barcode
Dim MyScan      As String      ' Enter ScanDate
Dim MyDirectory As String

MyBarCode = Application.InputBox("Please enter the barcode", "Bar Code", Type:=2)
If MyBarCode = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
Do
    MyScan = Application.InputBox("Please enter scan date", "Scan Date", Date, Type:=2)
    If MyScan = "False" Then Exit Sub   'user canceled
    If IsDate(MyScan) Then Exit Do
    MsgBox "Please enter a valid date format. ", vbExclamation, "Invalid Date Entry"
Loop

Range("B20").Value = MyBarCode
Range("B21").Value = CDate(MyScan)

MyDirectory = "N:\1_DATA\MicroArray\NexusData\" & MyBarCode & "_" & Format(CDate(MyScan), "m-d-yyyy") & "\"
' Create nexus directory and folder
If Dir(MyDirectory, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir MyDirectory

If MsgBox("The project file has been created. " & _
          "Do you want to create a template for analysis now?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    'Write to text file
    Open MyDirectory & "sample_descriptor.txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, "Experiment Sample" & vbTab & "Control Sample" & vbTab & "Display Name" & vbTab & "Gender" & vbTab & "Control Gender" & vbTab & "Spikein" & vbTab & "SpikeIn Location" & vbTab & "Barcode"
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block1.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block1.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B12").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block2.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block2.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block3.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block3.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("D9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("D12").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Value
    Print #1, MyBarCode & "_532Block4.txt" & vbTab & MyBarCode & "_635Block4.txt" & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E8").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E11").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("E12").Value & vbTab & ActiveSheet.Range("B20").Value
    Close #1

    'Run ImaGene
    If MsgBox("Please run the ImaGene analysis. " & _
          "and click yes after it completes to verify the spike-ins.", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

    'Update folder structure and call perl
    Dim PathCrnt As String
    Dim Wsh As Object
    Dim WaitOnReturn As Boolean
    Dim WindowStyle As Integer

    PathCrnt = MyDirectory
    Set Wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WaitOnReturn = True
    WindowStyle = 1

    Wsh.Run PathCrnt & "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat", WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn

End If
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing has been done. ", vbExclamation, "Goodbye!"
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect the `err` object (particularly `err.Description`) after wsh.Run.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim PathCrnt As String
Dim wsh As Object

PathCrnt = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & MyBarCode & "_" & MyScan
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
Dim errrCode As Long

errrCode = wsh.Run( "cmd /C ""C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat""" _
     , windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

If errrCode = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Done! No error to report."
Else
    MsgBox "Program exited with error code " & errrCode & "."
End If
```

Note

- explicitly run `cmd /c`;
- enclose batch script (fully qualified) name in double quotes;
- get (and treat) `errrCode` from called batch script.

If your batch script requires paramer(s), use them as follows (an example):

```
errrCode = wsh.Run( "cmd /C ""C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat"" par1 ""par 2""" _
    , windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Another example:

```
errrCode = wsh.Run( "cmd /C ""C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat"" " _
   _ & """" & PathCrnt & """" , windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Comment: I edited the original post and the code does run but exits with error code 1.  I hope I outlined what I am trying to do correctly and thank you :).

Comment: Maybe you could inspect batch error(s) using `cmd /K` instead of `cmd /C`

Comment: Examing the batch error revealed this: `'\\path\users\C\CMcCabe'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
'C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat' is not recognized as an internal or ex
ternal command,
operable program or batch file.`.... I understand the first part of the error but the path to the batch file listed is correct, so I'm not sure why the error?  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris I'm lost; try `Wsh.Run "cmd /K pushd """ & PathCrnt & """ ^&  ""C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\NxClinical.bat""", WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn`

Comment: I get `'\\path.org\users\C\CMcCabe'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
The specified path is invalid.` program exited with error code -1073741510.  Thank you for your help :).

Comment: @Chris [add the value `DisableUNCCheck` REG_DWORD and set the value to `1`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/156276) under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` registry key?

Comment: I added the registry and get `The specified path is invalid.

\\path\users\C\CMcCabe>`  Not sure what else to do but appreciate your help.  Thank you :).